# facing difficulty after running chat in python

Tags: python-3.x, chatterbot

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\test\AI_ChatBot_Python-master\new.py", line 2, in 
chatbot = ChatBot(
File "C:\Users\atulk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 34, in **init**
self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\atulk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 54, in initialize_class
return Class(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\atulk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 22, in **init**
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
File "C:\Users\atulk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy_*init*_.py", line 8, in 
from . import util as *util  # noqa
File "C:\Users\atulk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util_*init**.py", line 14, in 
from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg  # noqa
File "C:\Users\atulk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util_collections.py", line 16, in 
from .compat import binary_types
File "C:\Users\atulk\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 264, in 
time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you're running this from Python version **<3.8** because `time.clock()` has been removed in Python 3.8 or you can simply upgrade sqlalchemy which supports `perf_counter` as replacement.

[Python v3.8 changes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#api-and-feature-removals)

[sqlalchemy with time perf_counter](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py#L137)

[sqlalchemy with time.clock](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_2/lib/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py#L264)